# Bluetooth data streaming

Tags: bluetooth

Does Bluetooth classic BR/EDR enable streaming of uncompressed data.  The data rate is typically 32768 bits per sec.  I don't want to use the RFCOMM protocol.  I'm trying to find something similar to a UDP socket.  You just pour bytes in one end and they come out the other end.  The data will be in packets at the application layer.  It is the average data rate that is important.
If so, what protocol or profile would I use?